# how to delete an element in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

good day, i tried to search online looking for sample on how to delete an element in 2d array with no avail. forgive me if my questions seems unclear and amateur.

what is the simple code for deleting a specific  element in 2d array?
i am using a static array and haven't learn yet about dynamic and vectors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

std::string array[3][6] = {{"a","b","c","d","e","f",},
                            {"g","h","i","j","k","l",},
                            {" "," "," "," "," "," ",}}; //i made some allowance so that i can insert/delete

void display();

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char xdelete;
    char ydelete;

    display();

    cout<<"\nDelete character" <<endl;
    cout<<"enter position x: "; 
    cin>>xdelete; 
    cout<<"enter position y: ";
    cin>>ydelete;

    for(int x = xdelete; x<2; x++){
        for(int y = ydelete ;y<6;y++){
            array[x][y] = array[x][y+1]; // yup, this is wrong >.<
        }
    }

    display();

}

//display
void display(){

    cout<<endl;
    for(int z = 0; z<6; z++){
        cout<<"  "<<z;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int x = 0; x<2; x++){
    cout<<x <<"|";
        for(int y = 0; y<6; y++){
            cout<<" " <<array[x][y] <<" "; 
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

this is the given: enter position x: 0 
                   enter position y: 1

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a  b  c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
```

this is the output that i want

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a  c  d  e  f  g
1| h  i  j  k  l
```

Comment: you need to define what "delete an element from a 2d array" means. Do you ... shift the row, shift the column... how should the array look after the deletion?

Comment: @bolov sorry, i edited it just now

Comment: Well, you should have learned std::vector first, and C-style arrays only when you need to use some old code that someone else wrote.

Comment: Using `using namespace std;` like that can lead to surprises down the line. Try adding the header `#include <array>` at the top and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to remove elements from an array. An array `T[N]` contains exactly `N` number of elements of type `T` throughout its entire lifetime.

Another operation, that is similar to removal, is to assign all of the successive elements one index to their left, such that the element in the "removed" index will have been overwritten. This will leave the element at the last index to be a copy of the second to last index.

Comment: thanks. i see, so there is no such thing as "removing" and it was actually replacing it by the next element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer `for` loop, you can just use `xdelete` to access the row.

And in the `y` loop you have to stop at `y < 5`, otherwise you'll access outside the row. After the loop you should replace the following element with a blank, otherwise you'll have a duplicate of the last item in the row.

```
int y;
for (y = ydelete; y < 5; y++) {
    array[xdelete][y] = array[xdelete][y+1];
}
array[xdelete][y] = " ";
```

Comment: thank you for replying, so what if i want to delete something in the second row? does "y" will handle that?  for (y = ydelete; y < 4; y++) , why is y<4? for example if i want to delete array[0][0] will that be adjust the array?

Comment: `xdelete` contains the row that you want to delete from. If you want to delete `array[0][0]`, it will slide everything in the first row over.

Comment: I was wrong about `y < 4`, it should be `y < 5`. The number of elements in each row is 6, so the highest index is 5. So you have to stop when `y == 4`, otherwise `y + 1` will be outside the row.

Comment: sorry for bothering you. it still giving me error when i tried your code, my compiler has stopped working.

Comment: The problem is that you have `using namespace std;`, and `std::array` conflicts with your `array` variable. Change it to something like `myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the actual number of elements in the array and it will be simpler to interpret the array as a one-dimensional array when some operations as deleting an element are performed with the array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::ostream & display( const std::string *a, size_t n, size_t cols, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        os << a[i] << ( ( i + 1 ) %  cols == 0 ? '\n' : ' ' ); 
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 3, N = 6;
    std::string array[M][N] = 
    {
        { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", },
        { "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", },
    };

    auto it = std::find( *array, *array + M * N, std::string() );

    size_t n = std::distance( *array, it );

    display( *array, n, N ) << std::endl;

    size_t row, col;

    std::cout<<"Delete character\n";
    std::cout << "enter row: "; 
    std::cin >> row; 
    std::cout << "enter column: ";
    std::cin >> col;

    if ( N * row + col < n )
    {
        size_t pos = N * row + col;

        std::move( *array + pos + 1, *array + n, *array + pos );
        --n;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    display( *array, n, N ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
a b c d e f
g h i j k l

Delete character
enter row: 0
enter column: 1

a c d e f g
h i j k l
```

Answer (score 0):

A Little bit of repeating here, with extra suggestions

As others, said, you CAN'T remove elements from the array, you can shift them.
Regarding your code: it does shift (just change the name `array`, and change types of `xdelete` and `ydelete` to `int`s., however, with `[y + 1]`  you eventually go out of bounds, which causes problems.

In order to get even closer to deleting in static 2d arrays, after you shift the initial array, you create a new array with size = (originalsize - 1), and copy everything from the first one to the seconds one (except the last element);

Comment: thanks you for pointing out my mistake, no wonder the elements are not shifting. yes it y(column) is causing me some problems  i change the y<5 and the second row element h disappeared. what do you mean create another array, the original size which is "y" will be -1 right? thanks

Comment: Literally, create second array. For this example, y - 1 for the size will be sufficient. Just don't forget to check, if (y - 1) == 0. If it is, you want to do x--, and return y to the original value.

Comment: my comprehension about this is not that good and im spending quite sometime figuring out how to do your tips. i apologize, can you show me a code so that i can figure it out. thanks

Comment: You will have to go it if (y - 1 > 0) { string newArr[x][y]; //continue here} Keep in mind, newArr is local here, so it will be deleted once you go out of scope. This example is ok as learning experience but it has no practical use. Thus, try to learn dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 0):

(say) I have an integer array - `A[3][4]`
If you are unsure of how to shift first item of next row to the place of last item of current row then this could be a possible solution:

```
//Deleting an item from the array
int Row,Column;
cout<<endl<<"Enter the index from where you wish to delete the item: ";
cin>>Row>>Column;
int Deleted;
Deleted=A[Row][Column];
for(int i=Row; i<3;i++){
    int n=0;
    for(int j=Column; j<4; j++){
        n++;
        if(n==3)
            A[i][j]= A[i+1][(j+1)%4];
        else
            A[i][j]= A[i][(j+1)%4];
    }
}
cout<<endl<<"Item deleted"<< "="<<Deleted<<endl;
//Displaying Array after deleting the item
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
     cout<<" "<< A[i][j];
    }
}
```